# Conky window improperly sized for output

Tags: xubuntu, conky

I'm using the following conky script, which works just fine...until I remove the comments from lines 43 and/or 44 - which draw a battery icon in my conky window.  The question I have is how do I enable this new functionality without creating blank space at the bottom of the window?

Version Information:
- Conky 1.9.0 compiled Fri May 10 23:14:51 UTC 2013 for Linux 3.2.0-37-generic (i686)
- XUbuntu 13.10 (32-bit)

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- .conkyrc
# Purpose:    Conky Configuration File
# Requires:   sudo apt-get install cpufrequtils lm-sensors && sudo sensors-detect && sudo service kmod start
# ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈

  alignment                   middle_right                  # Display on right edge of screen, vertically centered
  background                  yes                           # Fork to background
  cpu_avg_samples             3                             # Sample and average CPU cores three times
  default_bar_size            208 10                        # Set bar height
  default_color               gold                          # Set default text color to gold
  double_buffer               yes                           # Enable double buffering to eliminate flicker
  gap_x                       6                             # Offset horizontal placement to allow a one pixel gap between window and screen edge
  gap_y                       0                             # Make conky respect the vertical centering
  if_up_strictness            link                          # An ethernet connection is only considered to be up if there's an active link
  maximum_width               297                           # Set width - 307px
  max_user_text               24576                         # Maximum size of user text buffer (layout below TEXT line in config file) - Default is 16384 bytes
  minimum_size                297                           # Set width - 307px
  net_avg_samples             3                             # Sample and average network activity three times
  no_buffers                  yes                           # Disregard file system buffers when calculating memory usage
  own_window                  yes                           # Required to minimize double buffer size
  own_window_argb_value       191                           # Set conky background opacity (0 transparent, 63-127-191 25-50-75% translucent, 255 opaque)
  own_window_argb_visual      yes                           # Enable ARGB settings
  own_window_hints            undecorated                   # No window decorations
  own_window_hints            below                         # Always visible as a desktop element
  own_window_hints            sticky                        # Sticky across workspaces
  own_window_hints            skip_taskbar                  # Do not display to taskbar
  own_window_hints            skip_pager                    # Do not display to other application switchers
  pad_percents                3                             # Stabilize layout
  temperature_unit            celsius                       # Show temperatures in Celsius
  top_name_width              20                            # Set top name width
  update_interval             0.5                           # Set update speed
  use_spacer                  left                          # Stabilize layout
  use_xft                     yes                           # Employ XFT anti-aliased fonts
  xftfont                     DejaVu Sans Mono:size=9       # Select an appropriate font and size
# default_bar_size            192 12                        # Set bar height
# top_name_width              15                            # Set top name width
# xftfont                     DejaVu Sans Mono:size=10      # Select an appropriate font and size

TEXT
# ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ Header
${voffset -6}${alignc}${color green}${exec whoami}@${nodename}
${voffset -15}${if_match "${battery_short}" == "C"}${color yellow}${endif}${if_match "${battery_short}" == "D"}${color red}${endif}${if_match "${battery_short}" == "U"}${color white}${endif}
#ISSUE HERE: ${voffset -13}${alignr 5}${battery_bar 10,35}
#ISSUE HERE: ${voffset -15}${alignr 2}${entropy_bar 4,3}${voffset -2}
${voffset -2}${alignc}${color lightblue}${exec cat /etc/*release | grep "PRETTY_NAME" | cut -c13-100 | cut -d '"' -f 2} (${if_match "${machine}" == "i686"}32${else}64${endif}-bit)
${voffset -7}${color cyan}${hr}
# ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈
#
# ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ Calendar and Clock
${voffset -6} ${execi 60 cal -h | head --lines=1}
${color black}${execpi 60 calendar=`date +%_d`; cal -h | sed '1d' | sed '/./!d' | sed 's/$/ /' | fold -w 21 | sed -n '/^.\{21\}/p' | sed 's/^/ /' | sed /" ${calendar} "/s/" ${calendar} "/" "''"${calendar}"'${color black}'" "/}
${voffset -106}${offset -1}${color purple}${execpi 60 calendar=`date +%_d`; cal -h | sed '1d' | sed '/./!d' | sed 's/$/ /' | fold -w 21 | sed -n '/^.\{21\}/p' | sed 's/^/ /' | sed /" ${calendar} "/s/" ${calendar} "/" "'${color green}'"${calendar}"'${color purple}'" "/}
${voffset -119}${alignr} ------------------- 
${alignr} ------------------- 
${alignr} ------------------- 
${alignr} ------------------- 
${alignr} ------------------- 
${alignr} ------------------- 
${alignr}${color purple} --- ${color}${time %r}${color purple} --- 
${voffset -10}${color cyan}${stippled_hr}
# ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈
#
# ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ System specs
${voffset -5}${color purple}Uptime:${alignr}${color}${uptime}
# ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈
#
# ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ CPU monitoring
${voffset 6}${color purple}CPU:   ${color white}${if_match ${hwmon 1 temp 2} >= 50}${color cyan}${endif}${if_match ${hwmon 1 temp 2} >= 60}${color green}${endif}${if_match ${hwmon 1 temp 2} >= 70}${exec aplay ~/alarm.wav}${color}${endif}${if_match ${hwmon 1 temp 2} >= 80}${color orange}${endif}${if_match ${hwmon 1 temp 2} >= 90}${color red}${endif}${if_match ${hwmon 1 temp 2} >= 95}${blink ${hwmon 1 temp 2}°C}${else}${hwmon 1 temp 2}°C${endif}${alignr}${color lightblue}${exec cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor} ${color lightblue}@ ${freq_g 0}GHz
${if_existing /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0}${color purple} Core 1:${color}${cpu cpu1}% ${if_match ${cpu cpu1} < 25}${color green}${endif}${if_match ${cpu cpu1} > 75}${color red}${endif}${cpubar cpu1}
${endif}${if_existing /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1}${voffset -2}${color purple} Core 2:${color}${cpu cpu2}% ${if_match ${cpu cpu2} < 25}${color green}${endif}${if_match ${cpu cpu2} > 75}${color red}${endif}${cpubar cpu2}
${endif}${if_existing /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2}${voffset -2}${color purple} Core 3:${color}${cpu cpu3}% ${if_match ${cpu cpu3} < 25}${color green}${endif}${if_match ${cpu cpu3} > 75}${color red}${endif}${cpubar cpu3}
${endif}${if_existing /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3}${voffset -2}${color purple} Core 4:${color}${cpu cpu4}% ${if_match ${cpu cpu4} < 25}${color green}${endif}${if_match ${cpu cpu4} > 75}${color red}${endif}${cpubar cpu4}
${endif}${if_existing /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4}${voffset -2}${color purple} Core 5:${color}${cpu cpu5}% ${if_match ${cpu cpu5} < 25}${color green}${endif}${if_match ${cpu cpu5} > 75}${color red}${endif}${cpubar cpu5}
${endif}${if_existing /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5}${voffset -2}${color purple} Core 6:${color}${cpu cpu6}% ${if_match ${cpu cpu6} < 25}${color green}${endif}${if_match ${cpu cpu6} > 75}${color red}${endif}${cpubar cpu6}
${endif}${if_existing /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6}${voffset -2}${color purple} Core 7:${color}${cpu cpu7}% ${if_match ${cpu cpu7} < 25}${color green}${endif}${if_match ${cpu cpu7} > 75}${color red}${endif}${cpubar cpu7}
${endif}${if_existing /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7}${voffset -2}${color purple} Core 8:${color}${cpu cpu8}% ${if_match ${cpu cpu8} < 25}${color green}${endif}${if_match ${cpu cpu8} > 75}${color red}${endif}${cpubar cpu8}${endif}
# ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈
#
# ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ RAM monitoring
${voffset 6}${color purple}RAM:    ${color}${memperc}% ${if_match ${memperc} < 25}${color green}${endif}${if_match ${memperc} > 75}${color red}${endif}${membar}
${voffset -1}${color purple} Used:${color}${alignr 31}${mem}   ${color purple}Total: ${color}${alignr}${memmax} 
# ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈
#
# ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ Filesystem monitoring
${voffset 6}${color purple}Home:   ${color}${fs_used_perc /home}% ${if_match ${fs_used_perc /home} < 25}${color green}${endif}${if_match ${fs_used_perc /home} > 75}${color red}${endif}${fs_bar /home}
${voffset -1}${color purple} Used:${color}${alignr 31}${fs_used /home}   ${color purple}Total: ${color}${alignr}${fs_size /home} 
# ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈
#
# ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ Wired Network Status
${voffset 6}${color purple}LAN: ${alignr}${if_up eth0}${color cyan}Connected
 ${voffset -1}${color purple}MAC Address: ${alignr}${color}${execi 1800 ifconfig eth0 | grep eth0 | cut -c39-55 | awk '{ print toupper($1) }'} 
 ${voffset -2}${color purple}L: ${alignr 157}${color}${addr eth0}
 ${voffset -15}${color purple}                      R: ${alignr}${color}${execi 1800 curl -s http://checkip.dyndns.org/ | cut -d : -f 2- | cut -d \< -f -1 | sed 's/[^0-9.]*//g'} 
 ${voffset -2}${color purple}↑:${color}${alignr 157}${upspeedf eth0} KiB/s
 ${voffset -15}${color purple}                      ↓:${alignr}${color}${downspeedf eth0} KiB/s ${else}${color red}Offline${endif}
# ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈
#
# ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ Wireless Status
${voffset 6}${color purple}WiFi: ${color}${if_up wlan0}${if_match "  unk" == "${wireless_link_qual_perc wlan0}"}${alignr}${color white}Broadcast${else}${wireless_link_qual_perc wlan0}% ${color red}${if_match ${wireless_link_qual_perc wlan0} > 33}${color}${endif}${if_match ${wireless_link_qual_perc wlan0} > 67}${color green}${endif}${wireless_link_bar wlan0}${endif}
 ${voffset -1}${color purple}SSID: ${alignr}${color}${wireless_essid wlan0} 
 ${voffset -2}${color purple}MAC Address:  ${alignr}${color}${wireless_ap wlan0} 
 ${voffset -2}${color purple}L: ${alignr 157}${color}${addr wlan0}
 ${voffset -15}${color purple}                      R: ${alignr}${color}${if_match "  unk" == "${wireless_link_qual_perc wlan0}"}N/A${else}${execi 1800 curl -s http://checkip.dyndns.org/ | cut -d : -f 2- | cut -d \< -f -1 | sed 's/[^0-9.]*//g'}${endif} 
 ${voffset -2}${color purple}↑:${color}${alignr 157}${upspeedf wlan0} KiB/s
 ${voffset -15}${color purple}                      ↓:${color}${alignr}${downspeedf wlan0} KiB/s${else}${alignr}0% ${color red}${execbar echo 0}
${voffset -17}${alignr -1}${blink ----------------------------}${endif} 
# ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈
#
# ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ Networking
${if_gw}${voffset 6}${color purple}Connections:
 ${voffset -1}${color purple}Inbound: ${alignr 164}${color}${tcp_portmon 1 32767 count}
 ${voffset -15}${color purple}                      Outbound: ${alignr}${color}${tcp_portmon 32768 61000 count} 
 ${voffset -2}${color purple}Ping (Google): ${alignr}${color}${texeci 10 ping -c 1 -W 1 74.125.29.105 | grep time= | awk '{print $7}' | cut -c 6-100} ms 
 ${voffset -2}${color purple}Ping (Bing): ${alignr}${color}${texeci 10 ping -c 1 -W 1 204.79.197.200 | grep time= | awk '{print $7}' | cut -c 6-100} ms 
# ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈
#
# ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ Weather monitoring
${voffset 6}${color purple}Weather (KTTN):${alignr}${color}${execi 3600 curl -s http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/observations/metar/decoded/KTTN.TXT | grep "Sky conditions" | awk '{print $3}'} 
 ${voffset -1}${color purple}Temp C: ${alignr 157}${color}${execi 3600 curl -s http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/observations/metar/decoded/KTTN.TXT | grep "Temperature" | awk '{print $4}' | cut -c2-100}°C
 ${voffset -15}${color purple}                      Temp F: ${alignr}${color}${execi 3600 curl -s http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/observations/metar/decoded/KTTN.TXT | grep "Temperature" | awk '{print $2}'}°F 
 ${voffset -2}${color purple}Dew Point C: ${alignr 157}${color}${execi 3600 curl -s http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/observations/metar/decoded/KTTN.TXT | grep "Dew Point" | awk '{print $5}' | cut -c2-100}°C
 ${voffset -15}${color purple}                      Dew Point F: ${alignr 7}${color}${execi 3600 curl -s http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/observations/metar/decoded/KTTN.TXT | grep "Dew Point" | awk '{print $3}'}°F${endif}
# ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈
#
# ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ Environment monitoring
${voffset -10}${color cyan}${stippled_hr}
${voffset -5}${color purple}Processes${alignr 3}PID   CPU%   MEM%
${voffset -1}${color lightblue} ${top name 1} ${color}${top pid 1} ${top cpu 1} ${top mem 1}
${voffset -2}${color lightblue} ${top name 2} ${color}${top pid 2} ${top cpu 2} ${top mem 2}
${voffset -2}${color lightblue} ${top name 3} ${color}${top pid 3} ${top cpu 3} ${top mem 3}
${voffset -2}${color lightblue} ${top name 4} ${color}${top pid 4} ${top cpu 4} ${top mem 4}
${voffset -2}${color lightblue} ${top name 5} ${color}${top pid 5} ${top cpu 5} ${top mem 5}
# ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround for the issue noted above.  I have been experimenting with voffset, and came up with this to end the conky config with.

```
${voffset -42}
```

This neatly deletes the erroneous blank space.  Thanks for acting as a sounding board while I came up with this.  I hope this fix helps others who come up against this issue.

Comment: I think it's a side effect of all the other voffset's in your script, not sure why. Maybe a new line allocates space in the conky window, but the voffset moves the content up or down regardless of the window. My script has the same thing & the same fix.

Comment: When I comment out the specified lines (dealing with battery_bar or entropy_bar), or use this workaround, the problem disappears.  I use plenty of voffsets in my conky setup, so if the problem (and not the solution as I found) lay with them, it would have been alot harder to try to try to find this fix.

Comment: Another thing that causes window size problems can be a comment in the middle of a line, or just commenting out a whole line; it "hides" the newline character at the end of the line, and changes the window size again. Maybe a permanent fix might be conky actually looking at how far down the "used" parts of a window are, and adjusting the window size to fit (unless there's an override min or max window size). That'd be a programming patch though, maybe there's a good reason they don't do that, or might cause more headaches?

Comment: A good thing to keep in mind, surely, but in this particular case the problem is definitely in the bars (as commenting out those lines in their entirety solves the issue at the expense of not drawing the battery icon I put together) and the voffset at the end of the conkyrc TEXT does function as a workaround to solve this mysterious issue.